# Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac keeps reconnecting

Tags: windows-10, networking, mac, vpn, remote-desktop

I have the following problem with Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac.

When I try to connect to Windows 10 client from Mac via RDP using external IP address the client connects, I can enter the user password for login and as soon as the desktop shows up it freezes and soon after gray reconnecting screen appears, after reconnecting few seconds elapse and again the same scenario. Some times it starts reconnecting already on the login screen. Sometimes after some time, and 5, 15 or more reconnections it starts to work in a stable manner for an hour or more then all of the sudden it starts the reconnecting process again.

When I connect via VPN and then via RDP using local IP (intranet IP of the Windows 10 client) the connection works fine without the reconnecting process occurring.

It is surely no connection issue as VPN protocol adds some overhead and the RDP over VPN works fine with that extra overhead data while direct RDP protocol via external IP has some problems causing reconnection issues.

I was trying to fix that by disabling temporarily the Windows Defender Firewall completely and disabling the Antivirus protection, but it did not change anything.

Did anyone face similar problems and perhaps found any solution? Does anyone have any clue why the RDP connection via VPN works seamlessly and using external IP it constantly tries to reconnect?

What is interesting when I connect to Windows Server 2019 Standard via RDP it works fine both via external IP and via VPN intranet IP.

My configuration:

MacBook Air 13" Early 2015 running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 Tried Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac 10.4.1 (1825) and Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta for Mac 10.5.0 (1826) - same problems on both. Windows 10 Pro version 1909 compilation 18363.1139.

Thank you very much in advance for any assistance.

Regards,

Piotr

Comment: Have you tried to update the windows 10 or remote connect to another windows client with same version?

Comment: Hi @Seven, Winows 10 is being updated via Windows Update service on a regular basis and same situation happens when trying to connect to another Windows 10 client regardless of the version, although I was trying mostly with same one due to the fact all are being updated regularly.